# Can you always decompose an $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ into the sum of a monotonic function and a periodic function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, periodic-functions, monotone-functions

Is there a nice class of functions, like smooth or smooth and bounded, such that you can always decompose an $f: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ into the sum of a monotonic function and a periodic function? It seems true to me but I can't find a reference.

An equivalent question is if you can decompose a sufficiently nice odd $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ into the sum of a monotonic function and a periodic function.

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). It's particularly important that you show your work on the problem.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that such decomposition exists?

Comment: Are you assuming any kind of continuity?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Yes, I just edited the question to clarify. Suppose we can add any "niceness" conditions we need, does such a decomposition hold. Niceness could be smooth or smooth and bounded or whatever else an answerer wants.

Comment: How would you decompose $f(x)=\sin(x)$ (or any periodic function)? Or do you mean "nondecreasing" instead of "increasing"?

Comment: @Taladris "monotonic"="nondecreasing", so $g(x):=0$ is monotonic and thus $f(x) = g(x) + \sin(x)$

Comment: @jjagmath Yes the reason is that I can't think of an example that provably doesn't work.

Comment: @John_Krampf I posted an answer. By the way, to get $\infty$ type `\infty`

Comment: @John_Krampf: I misread the question. Thanks

Comment: @Taladris thanks for the attention all the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$. That function is smooth (actually analytic), bounded and can't be written as a sum of a monotonic function and a periodic function.

Comment: Maybe should be a follow-up question, but: how about a uniformly continuous analytic function?

Comment: @MeesdeVries $f(x) = \sin(x) + \sin(\pi x)$

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks for your response to my question, I have accepted the answer.

Comment: @John_Krampf The function $f(x) = \sin(x) + \sin(\pi x)$ is NOT periodic.

Comment: @jjagmath thank you